# Cannot sync data from network after stop node for long time

Tags: stellar-core, testnet

I started a new node both horizon and core with this [docker image](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon) in ***TESTNET*** with [default configuration](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon/blob/master/testnet/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg) and persistent mode. After started it reached state Synced!, then I had stopped the docker container for a day. When I started it again it stuck at state `Caching up`

Here is a result when I ran a command `stellar-core -c info`

```
Content-Length: 1373
Content-Type: application/json

2018-11-08T08:41:48.088 GAD7M [default INFO] {
"info" : {
  "UNSAFE_QUORUM" : "UNSAFE QUORUM ALLOWED",
  "build" : "v10.0.0",
  "history" : {
     "cache" : {
        "failure" : 0,
        "success" : 0
     },
     "h1" : {
        "failure" : 0,
        "success" : 0
     },
     "h2" : {
        "failure" : 0,
        "success" : 0
     },
     "h3" : {
        "failure" : 0,
        "success" : 0
     }
  },
  "ledger" : {
     "age" : 61751,
     "baseFee" : 100,
     "baseReserve" : 5000000,
     "closeTime" : 1541604757,
     "hash" : "4a57261e26d223a5ac0a65fe2c008b77eab0842304bd328ce1d56752c139cb9e",
     "maxTxSetSize" : 100,
     "num" : 572654,
     "version" : 10
  },
  "network" : "Test SDF Network ; September 2015",
  "peers" : {
     "authenticated_count" : 8,
     "pending_count" : 0
  },
  "protocol_version" : 10,
  "quorum" : {
     "11380688" : {
        "agree" : 2,
        "disagree" : 0,
        "fail_at" : 1,
        "hash" : "273af2",
        "missing" : 1,
        "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE"
     }
  },
  "startedOn" : "2018-11-08T06:13:02Z",
  "state" : "Joining SCP",
  "status" : [
     "Catching up: Waiting for trigger ledger: 11380688/11380737, ETA: 245s"
  ]
 }
}
```

A result when I run `stellar-core --c 'quorum'`

```
Content-Length: 4765
Content-Type: application/json

2018-11-08T08:47:15.037 GAFMP [default INFO] {
 "node" : "GDFWEBKJI6SCFINX5TT2GCBEKAD72OWVQ7YQCY553RVR3CHMNY5OSRFC",
 "slots" : {
   "11380687" : {
     "agree" : 2,
     "disagree" : null,
     "fail_at" : 1,
     "fail_with" : [ "sdf2" ],
     "hash" : "273af2",
     "missing" : [ "sdf1" ],
     "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE",
     "value" : {
        "t" : 2,
        "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
     }
   },
  "11380688" : {
     "agree" : 2,
     "disagree" : null,
     "fail_at" : 1,
     "fail_with" : [ "sdf2" ],
     "hash" : "273af2",
     "missing" : [ "sdf1" ],
     "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE",
     "value" : {
        "t" : 2,
        "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
     }
  },
  "11380689" : {
     "agree" : 0,
     "disagree" : null,
     "fail_at" : 0,
     "fail_with" : null,
     "hash" : "273af2",
     "missing" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ],
     "phase" : "unknown",
     "value" : {
        "t" : 2,
        "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Right now I solved by running new container (use new data)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues some days back. This is how I was able to fix mine.

- stop stellar core and horizon
- access the stellar core database and truncate the `peers` table.
- restart stellar core, wait for it to sync then start horizon